# Selenium ERROR : stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: java, eclipse, angularjs, google-chrome, selenium

I keep getting this error, I am need to testing so it maybe my code but I am not sure.

Here is my code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\selenium-2.44.0\\chromedriver.exe");
//  System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\selenium-2.44.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
//  WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
//  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("https://multichannel-custom-qa.Support/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("userID")).sendKeys("REH01");
    driver.findElement(By.name("j_password")).sendKeys("YE02year");
    driver.findElement(By.name("action")).submit();
    String tagName = "";

    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Workbench")).click();

    WebElement searchBox;
    searchBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='text']"));
    searchBox.sendKeys("X1508706");
    searchBox.findElement(By.cssSelector("css=button.btn.btn-default")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    searchBox.findElement(By.cssSelector("css=button.btn.btn-default"));
    searchBox.click();

    WebElement link;
    link = driver.findElement(By.linkText("X1508706"));
    link.click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
```

And here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=39.0.2171.95)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.12.301325 (962dea43ddd90e7e4224a03fa3c36a421281abb7),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 214 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:03:00'
System info: host: 'C9090DEF19ED258', ip: '172.22.46.117', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_20'
Session ID: e3c034f27280c888088da4ba7922cdee
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\kxh8178\AppData\Local\Temp\1\scoped_dir8948_22544}, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, version=39.0.2171.95, takesHeapSnapshot=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=false, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, applicationCacheEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:268)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:89)
    at driverTest.tests.main(tests.java:33)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure.. But, from your code, it seems **you are trying to click the same element twice**. And, probably the first click on the element results in a page refresh or something, resulting in DOM change, and hence in **StaleElementReferenceException**.

The below code snippet seems to be the culprit:

```
//1
searchBox.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.btn.btn-default")).click();

//2 
searchBox.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.btn.btn-default"));
searchBox.click();
```

As you can see, **Both code "//1" and "//2" perform the same action on the element.** If you remove any one of them, I think your problem will be solved.

Comment: Thanks for he reply, I took out that bit, but it just changed the error:           Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
  (Session info: chrome=39.0.2171.95)

Comment: I think the cssSelector is wrong here. Just replace **`css=button.btn.btn-default`** with only **`button.btn.btn-default`** as is the `classname` of the button I presume. Adding `css` is not the way to define a `cssSelector`.I have edited my code above accordingly. Please check if that works out for you.

Answer (score -4):

use this code to wait till the element is attached:

```
boolean breakIt = true;
        while (true) {
        breakIt = true;
        try {
            // write your code here
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e.getMessage().contains("element is not attached")) {
                breakIt = false;
            }
        }
        if (breakIt) {
            break;
        }

    }
```